Exclude page ID AND current page from wp_query of a Parent page
I would like to display a list of all children pages of parent page ID #2.
I exclude one of child page which is ID #4 :
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => '2', 'post__not_in' => array(4), 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ); $childrens = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $childrens->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $childrens->have_posts() ) : $childrens->the_post(); ?>
<p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

But I also would like to exclude the current page where I am.
Do you know how I could modify my code ? Probably include this current page in the 'post__not_in', but I don't know how (?)
Thanks in advance for your help ! :)

You can use get_the_ID() to retrieve the current page's ID.
$current_page_id = get_the_ID();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => '2',
    'post__not_in' => array( 4, $current_page_id ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
); 

This kind of ID exclusion may cause query performance issues, especially when you have a great number of posts. So another option is to do a simple if check within the posts loop and skip certain post(s).
if ( $children->have_posts() ) {
    $current_page_id = get_the_ID(); // ID of the page you're on
    
    while ( $children->have_posts() ) {
        $children->the_post();
        // compare loop iteration child page ID to the page ID
        if ( get_the_ID() === $current_page_id ) {
            continue;
        }
        ?>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <?php
    }
}


Thank you very much !

@Hellooo You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted to let the community know your issue is resolved. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer
